# 8 - Change taxonomy field's link text in view

Tags: views, theming, 8

In drupal 8 when creating a view for taxonomy terms and add a field I enabled

> Link to the Taxonomy term

option. The pathauto module is enabled so it gives following link:

`<a href="/site/taxonomy/taxonomy-term" hreflang="en">Taxonomy Term</a>`

But I want something like this:

`<a href="/site/taxonomy/taxonomy-term" hreflang="en">Read More</a>`

I have created a twig file views-view-field--my-region--name.html.twig as following:

`{{ output -}}`

I cannot go into more deeper with this setup. Can you help me to change the anchor text OR just get the taxonomy term url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view just add the field 'Taxonomy term: Link to Taxonomy term' and change the 'Text to display' to Read more.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Do you know the default machine name for this field?